# Чтение double из текстового файла и запись в массив

Tags: java

Как прочитать текстовый документ, заполненный числами (`double`), разделенными запятыми, и присвоить эти значения в новый массив?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Открыть файл для чтения.
2. Прочитать строку (которая *line*, а не *string*) из файла. Так как числа разделены запятыми, то они все находятся в первой строке файла.
3. Разбить строку на подстроки с помощью `split` по запятой.
4. Применить к каждой строке `Double.parseDouble` и сохранить полученные результаты в массиве.
5. Закрыть файл.

Код реализации:

```
try (FileReader fr = new FileReader("in.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr))
{
    String line = br.readLine();
    String[] numbersStrings = line.split(",");
    double[] numbers = new double[numbersStrings.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < numbersStrings.length; i++)
    {
        numbers[i] = Double.parseDouble(numbersStrings[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Код можно написать короче с использованием Java 8 (Stream-ы с [Files.lines()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-)):

```
try
{
    Path path = Paths.get("in.txt");
    double[] numbers = Files.lines(path)
            .flatMap(e -> Stream.of(e.split(",")))
            .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble)
            .toArray();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Гениально !!! Огромное Вам Спасибо !!!

Comment: подскажите, что делает этот кусочек кода  ?                                                     {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

Comment: @Cu100 выводит в консоль stacktrace произошедшей ошибки/исключения.

Comment: Хорошо, а как мне потом работать с этим массивом, например я хочу перебрать все значения по определенному параметру, например, for (int i=0; i<=numbers.length; i++).   но я получаю ошибку Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException.  Делать это все я собираюсь после вашего кода. Подскажите как правильно реализовать ?

Comment: @Cu100 можно, например, массив создать перед `try`: `double[] numbers = null;`, в `try` тогда будет `numbers = new double[numbersStrings.length];`. В таком случае вы сможете работать с массивом после try-catch.

Comment: Работает, спасибо !!!